# What made Well- Manicured Man to ask this question?

Tags: the-x-files

In the science fiction movie, *The X Files (1998)*, in London, a well-manicured man was called for a meeting. 
It was set by Conrad Strughold to inform him that a virus 
has been mutated into a new extraterrestrial biological entity.

> Conrad Strughold: While we've been waiting, we've seen surveillance
>   tapes that raise more concerns.
>
> Well- Manicured Man: **More concerns than what?**
>
> Conrad Strughold: We have been forced to reassess our role in 
>   colonization......by recently presented facts  of biology. The virus
>   has mutated.

He says, "More concerns than what" instead of "More concerns of what". Why?

Comment: Sounds like a short version of "We've got loads of concerns already.  Which one of them is this worse than ?".